# PACT тестирование

Tags: javascript, юнит-тесты

Использую [@pact-foundation/pact@latest](https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-js) (для быстроты развёртывания моего случая есть простой пример на [jest](https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-js/tree/master/examples/jest))

Используя данную конструкцию:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

у меня генерируется такой PACT-файл:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Генерируется он по спецификации 3 (это настройки):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проблема:

Как мне сделать так, чтобы итоговый PACT-файл содержал в себе `state params`?
Чтоб в итоге было так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Вот пример](https://habr.com/ru/post/451132/). Тут как раз `providerStates`. Но хотелось бы его получить через официальную библиотеку PACT.

Answer (score 1):

Ответ пришёл из англоязычной версии stackoverflow:

> This is not yet possible. Pact JS does not yet support the full
>   feature set of pact spec v3. See https://docs.pact.io/feature_support
>   for featur coverage across languages.

Автор ответа: [Matthew Fellows](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1008568/matthew-fellows)

[Ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56969689/cant-generate-params-in-state-pact-testing-problem/56984256) на оригинал (там есть [временный фикс](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56969689/cant-generate-params-in-state-pact-testing-problem/56978439#56984256) этой проблемы, написанный мной).

Вольный перевод:

> Это пока невозможно. Pact JS пока не поддерживает полный набор функций
>   спецификации пакта v3. Смотрите https://docs.pact.io/feature_support
>   для будущего охвата разными языками.